# No options, no shares available for short sale

Tags: trading, short-sale-property

I want to bet that certain stocks will decline in price, but they have no options and there are insufficient shares available for a short sale according to my broker. Do I have any other way to  take advantage of a potential decline in these stocks’ prices?

Comment: Well you'd have to find someone to take the other side of that bet which may be the root problem...

Comment: Any ideas on how to find such parties?

Comment: @ak87 If you are looking to short the stock, I would try a different broker. I think there is a good chance they will be able to help you.

Comment: As B.B. explains, simply another broker may do it easily.  However if that is NOT the case, the very simple answer is: "No".  You can not.

Answer (score 1):

If your stock does not offer options then you can check with other brokers to see if they have hard-to-borrow  shares available.  That's a long shot but still a possibility.

Another possibility is an OTC agreement with a counterparty but this is only available for big players since the intermediary is usually an investment bank or similar.

Comment: And to clarify, 'big players' in this case is measured in millions and billions, not hundreds and thousands.